# Removing layers from a leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am adding multiple layers with various opacities to my leaflet map object like this:

```
 var TopoLayer = L.esri.dynamicMapLayer("https://gis.in.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery_Basemap/MapServer", {
                        opacity: 0.8,
                        // Tell the map to use a loading control

                        useCors: false
                    }).addTo(map);
   var EPSLayer = L.esri.dynamicMapLayer("https://gis.in.gov/arcgis/rest/services/DOT/EPS_Map_2015/MapServer", {
                    opacity: 1,
                    // Tell the map to use a loading control

                    useCors: false
                }).addTo(map);
```

Now when a user clicks on a checkbox, I would like remove the layer or add it back. I have tried

```
                    map.removeLayer("EPSLayer");
                    map.removeLayer("tiles");
```

However, that didnt fix the issue. Any ideas or pointers that could help would be greatly appreciated.

*** Update I have created a fiddle to show the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/31gmr4ss/3/

The idea is to click on the tree icon to show the areial view and then switch to the map view when its clicked again.

It appears to work when the tree icon is clicked however the arial view is present when the map is zoomed.

As @Fabrizio has suggested, the remove should not be passed string values, however passing just variable names causes the map to not work at all.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't use strings in the function:

```
map.removeLayer(EPSLayer);
map.removeLayer(TopoLayer);
```

Depending on the layer you want to remove.

Comment: Fabrizio, I see that in documentation to not use strings. However when I change the code as you have suggested, I get the error JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property '_leaflet_id' of undefined or null reference Any idea why ?

Comment: What version of leaflet are you using?

Comment: 0.7.3 I am also using Leaflet geocoder version 1.0.0-rc.4

Comment: Maybe also add more code? Specifically the once that is firing the removeLayer() function?